# Enable/disable deployed components in jboss 6 using cli

Tags: jboss6.x, command-line-interface

Is there a way to disable/enable deployed components using the jboss cli for jboss 6.2.
I need to keep the components deployed on the server but disabled until needed.

EDIT:
Found a way to deploy modules as disabled adding the --disabled option in the cli file on that component.

Still looking for a way to enable modules through the cli.

EDIT 2:
Is there a way to disable a already deployed component without first un-deploying? --force can not be combined with --disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, do you mean JBoss EAP 6.x by jboss6? I don't know anything about CLI in JBoss 6. I didn't find a way to actively disable or enable deployments via CLI, but at least you can enable a disabled deployment with

```
deploy --name={your_deployment_name.ear/war}
```

See also https://community.jboss.org/thread/223931

Answer (score 9):

#### Deployment of a 'sample' web application

```
[standalone@localhost:9999 /] deploy /home/rudy/Downloads/sample.war
```

#### Disabling a 'sample' web application

```
[standalone@localhost:9999 /] undeploy sample.war --keep-content
```

#### Re-enabling a 'sample' web application

```
[standalone@localhost:9999 /] deploy --name=sample.war
```

#### Undeployment of a 'sample' web application

```
[standalone@localhost:9999 /] undeploy sample.war
```

Answer (score 7):

You can disable deployed components with `undeploy {deployment name} --keep-content`

Answer (score 1):

In standalone it works but in domain mode you can have your application in Content Repository as well as deployed on server-group but disabled. In such case command fails:

```
deploy --name=app.war --server-groups=your-server-group
 JBAS014803: Duplicate resource
```

To enable/disable without undeploy from server group you can type:

```
 /server-group=your-server-group/deployment=app.war:deploy
 /server-group=your-server-group/deployment=app.war:undeploy
```